# call api when video play after some duration

Tags: php, node.js, ffmpeg

Is it possible to split video in some time duration and set some text when merge video again?

After that I want to call API when that text come on video playing.

I did research for same but I didn't find anything for what I want.

Comment: You could always attach a click event handler to the play button and make note of the time and work out time played manually? Or better yet on play button click set a function to run after a defined interval? This function could call your api?

Comment: thank you for guidance.

if i want  to share a video on Facebook and there i want this functionality.